# R - What causes error when using USGS API?

Tags: r, api, connection

I was working with earthquake data at the [USGS catalog website](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/search/) and was lucky enough to stumble upon a [simple package](https://github.com/usgs/rcomcat/blob/master/searchcomcat.R) provided by the USGS for querying the catalog. It only has a single API function that queries the earthquake catalog and returns a dataframe. I'm getting a connection error, however.

```
> comcatdata <- comcathypocsv()
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

I've looked around for solutions, and found that many had remedied this with `setInternet2(TRUE)`, but this function is now defunct with no apparent replacement.

Would someone mind trying the package and the simple call above to see if they can get it to work or not?

**EDIT**

Well if anyone in some improbable future takes the thread off the shelf and dusts it off, here's a simple working function for basic queries:

```
get_quake_data <- function(output_format="csv",
                           starttime=today()-180,
                           endtime=today(),
                           minlatitude=27,
                           minlongitude=-103,
                           maxlatitude=33,
                           maxlongitude=-100,
                           minmagnitude=2.5,
                           maxmagnitude=10){

  # compose API request
  base_url <- "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?"

  # add format arg
  api_url <- paste0(base_url, "format=", output_format)

  # add start, end times
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&starttime=", starttime)
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&endtime=", endtime)

  # set longitude range
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&minlongitude=", minlongitude)
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&maxlongitude=", maxlongitude)

  # set latitude range
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&minlatitude=", minlatitude)
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&maxlatitude=", maxlatitude)

  # set magnitude range
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&minmagnitude=", minmagnitude)
  api_url <- paste0(api_url, "&maxmagnitude=", maxmagnitude)

  return(api_url)
}
```

@Dave2e deserves the bulk of the credit for pointing out correct URL.

Comment: http://comcat.cr.usgs.gov seems to be giving me a 'website not found' error, so it's no surprise. That code on github is about 4 years old, so it might well be out of date.

Comment: It looks like the USGS has a relative simple API anyway. See https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/